# rationale for posix tracing obsolescent?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, bsd

I began reading the POSIX standard, and I really appreciate the rationale sections, as they help me understand (and remember) the design. When I came to the "Tracing" system interface section, I saw that it's marked as obsolescent, but I can't find anywhere a reason why. Is it simply because nobody implemented it? Is there any public documentation on the reasoning behind this change?

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_11

Comment: Please leave a comment when you downvote.

Comment: The fundamental issues are enumerated in "[Replacing ptrace()](https://lwn.net/Articles/371501/)" by Jonathan Corbet, in [*LWN*](https://lwn.net), 27 January 2010. However, *"`ptrace()` is a standard function which is part of the kernel ABI; as long as users exist, it really cannot be removed from the kernel"*.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks. That's good reading, but I'm not able to make a direct connection to the posix tracing API, above. Is utrace somehow related to posix_trace? My question is why posix_trace has been removed from the standard (for posix-conforming applications).

Comment: I found [a document](http://ps-2.kev009.com/basil.holloway/ALL%20PDF/sg247559.pdf) which says that it was implemented in AIX, and gives some sample code. So you have to change your hypothesis from "nobody implemented it" to "nobody but IBM implemented it (or planned to)".