# some questions about posix_trace_* function

Tags: posix, trace

Recently, our team want to support more posix function on our os software.
I start to do some work about posix_trace_* api

I found that it is difficult to find some source code about these api, no matter in source code musl-c or glib-c

I find some opensource project such as strace and ptrace, the AI also suggest the gdb

If posix_trace_* api just a standard.
People always prefer to use ptrace or strace or gdb to debug their code
There are not some code about these posix_trace_* apis, right?

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126047/rationale-for-posix-tracing-obsolescent